# Mysql Table Updated after logout

Tags: php, mysql, session

please help me i want to update a mysql query after session destroy.
i have logout.php file in which i set update query but after seesion destory this will not updated
please tell me as soon as possible 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: share your codes mate

Answer (score 0):

TRY this code,
i hope it will be help.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy())
{
   $sql="your Query";
}
 else{
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: use condition and , after it use Query and redirect page  !! its work !!

Comment: Thanks for reply YOG PHP
But can you modify above code which i sent

Comment: Could you please send, well format code, its not understandable.

Comment: i paste above exact code through i want to update mysql table

Comment: please send me solution i am still wait of above question solution

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
require_once'db.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['crmuserName']))
  unset($_SESSION['crmuserName']);

  mysql_query("UPDATE user SET online='no' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['crmuserId']."");
  if(isset($_SESSION['userId']))
  unset($_SESSION['crmuserId']);
  header('Location:index.php');
```